# Time Out issue in HTML5/jQuery application

Tags: jquery, sql, wcf, clustered-index, webhttpbinding

I am developing an HTML5/jQuery application in .NET 4.0. The application is used to upload the excel files using WCF Rest services (**webHttp**). The uploaded files saved in SQL Server drop zone and then SSIS process them.

For **smaller files** (few KB) there is no problem. however when I tried to upload files of **size more than 2 MB** (up to 5 MB) I am seeing jQuery Error that **File can not be uploaded. Please try again**.

The issue is the file is being saved **successfully** in SQL Drop Zone (I can see it there that means **upload** is successful) but since ETL process is **taking lots of time** (around 5-10 min) **jQuery throws the error without waiting** for the response **from ETL (within 30 seconds)**.

This is my web.config look like:

```
        <webHttpBinding>     
             <binding name="webBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             transferMode="Streamed"
             sendTimeout="00:05:00">
                    <readerQuotas  maxDepth="2147483647"
                     maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                     maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                     maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                     maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
         </binding>
                   <security mode="Transport"></security>
       </webHttpBinding>
```

Is there a way I can resolve the issue so my application wait till it get the response from ETL (via WCF Service)?

### Edit

have been troubleshooting the issue and looks like Error is coming exactly after 30 seconds, no matter what settings I apply in web.config file as above.

So is there a way to increase this timeout to avoid the error?

```
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/DemoService.svc/FileUpload", timeout: 0, 
            data: obj,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) {
    //
            },
            error: function (Result) {
                $("#error").html("Unable to upload. Please try again!!!").removeClass("hide");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be the issue was with the SQL connection time out which is by default 30 seconds and then there was issues with the database table design (clustering).